# Django gives 404 Error from previous project

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

When I'm trying to start new Django project and to run server I have 
`"SOURCE /lo-fi-radio HTTP/1.0" 404 1987` But it's fully new empty project with its own virtualenv. `lo-fi-radio` is the root directory of my previous project. There are another strange errors too.

Full log:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader                                                                                                                                                     
Performing system checks...                                                                                                                                                                     

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).                                                                                                                                                 

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.                                          
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

October 02, 2019 - 17:32:41
Django version 2.2.6, using settings 'company_db_manager.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /lo-fi-radio
[02/Oct/2019 17:32:45] "SOURCE /lo-fi-radio HTTP/1.0" 404 1987
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 333, in send_headers
    self._write(bytes(self.headers))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[02/Oct/2019 17:32:45] "SOURCE /lo-fi-radio HTTP/1.0" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 36856)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 333, in send_headers
    self._write(bytes(self.headers))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/pavel/.virtualenvs/pbz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/pavel/.virtualenvs/pbz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/pavel/.virtualenvs/pbz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/pavel/.virtualenvs/pbz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

`pip freeze` under virtualenv gives

```
Django==2.2.6
psycopg2==2.8.3
pytz==2019.2
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

I don't even guess what the problem because it occurs with new empty project and I haven't copied any files from previous project.

UPD: reinstalling virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper don't help

Comment: how are you starting your virtual environment? are you using any kind of manager? how did you initialized it?

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz, just 'mkvirtualenv name' at the root folder of new project

Comment: Somewhere is a link to your old project. Did you set up django etc. again within the new virtual env? Did you use django etc. globally previously or did you install it within your old virtualenv?

Comment: @Phanti, yes, I did. I've made new virtualenv and then installed django at this virtualenv

Comment: could you post the settings.py of the new project // and what is lo-fi radio dir? old or new project path?

Comment: @Phanti, it's absolutely new project and it has default settings [gist](https://gist.github.com/Mafatik/1bd1bf9341b3ab60098428339669a033)

Comment: what is lo-fi radio dir? is this the old project? Try to allow `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` as host in your settings.py and try to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in your browser

Comment: @Phanti, yes, it's old project. localhost:8000 works fine, but I don't like that terrible logs

Comment: using localhost:8000 I assume you use Apache server or something? You should visit your Django server address which is the one from your command prompt `Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: @Phanti, the same effect. Default debug screen "The install worked successfully! Congratulations!"

Comment: puh. Are you 100% sure that you installed your new virtualenv + project in a different dir? And did you check the status of the other virtualenvs? they should be deactivated while your new one is running. The prompt is `workon` to get a status

Comment: @Phanti, 200%. Did it 2 times. By the way removed all another virtual envs

Comment: Did you try to move your old project to another dir and retry it? Can you access http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin?

Comment: @Phanti, yes. I even reinstalled Python, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. It's very strange

Comment: Wait, so the admin application is working?

Comment: @Phantu, yes, it works